# How to get logistical selected data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two dataframes X & Y, I want to get the data in X that with the same   value in Y.For example, 
X is like this:

```
    user_id sku_id  time             model_id   type    cate    brand
0   27630   37957   2016-02-01 07:43:14 NaN     6        8      489
1   65377   165713  2016-02-01 11:09:34 NaN     6        5      124
2   10396   65823   2016-02-01 08:20:59 NaN     6        6      78
    ……
```

and Y is like this:

```
       user_id  sku_id
8489    58104   79636
9043    99179   113675
9330    101391  39778
9468    65786   73834
……
```

the (user_id,sku_id) is not unique in X &Y. I want to select all the data which (user_id,sku_id) is in Y from X. It is not just isin(), because the user_id and the sku_id should be meet the requirement in the same time.

and I also want to find a more efficient way than merge().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `inner join` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(X, Y)
```

Or:

```
X.set_index(['user_id', 'sku_id'], inplace=True)
df = Y.join(X, how='inner', on=['user_id', 'sku_id'])
```

Another solution is [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), but it works only if unique `user_id`:

```
X = X.set_index('user_id')
df = X[X['sku_id'].isin(Y.set_index('user_id')['sku_id'])].reset_index()
```

Generally, the best and fastest is use `merge` in pandas:

```
In [143]: %%timeit
     ...: (Y1.join(X1.set_index(['user_id', 'sku_id']),how='inner',on=['user_id','sku_id']))
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 583 ms per loop

In [144]: %%timeit 
     ...: (pd.merge(X2,Y2))
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 487 ms per loop

In [145]: %%timeit
     ...: x = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([X['user_id'], X['sku_id']])
     ...: y = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Y['user_id'], Y['sku_id']])
     ...: inter = x.intersection(y)
     ...: a = X.set_index(['user_id', 'sku_id']).loc[inter].reset_index()
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 1.26 s per loop

#another solution
In [146]: %%timeit
     ...: X[(X['user_id'].astype(str) +"_" +X['sku_id'].astype(str)).isin((Y['user_id'].astype(str)+"_"+Y['sku_id'].astype(str)))]
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 6.34 s per loop
```

If all values are strings (`X = X.astype(str)`, `Y = Y.astype(str)`):

```
In [147]: %%timeit
     ...: X[(X['user_id'] +"_" +X['sku_id']).isin((Y['user_id']+"_"+Y['sku_id']))]
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 953 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
X = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':np.random.randint(10000, size=N),
                   'sku_id': np.random.randint(10000, size=N),
                   'brand':  np.random.randint(10000, size=N)})
X = X.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id', 'sku_id'])
print (X)
X1,X2 = X.copy(), X.copy()

Y = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':np.random.randint(10000, size=N),
                   'sku_id': np.random.randint(10000, size=N)})
print (Y)
Y = Y.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id', 'sku_id'])
Y1,Y2 = Y.copy(), Y.copy()
```

Comment: I want to find more efficient way to get that. merge() costs a lot of time.

Comment: @Husy - are you sure another solution is faster? Because if need cast int columns to str, it is slowier. Check my timings. Or is not necessary convert columns to `strings` ?

Comment: it's yours. many thanks! My columns are strings, not int, though they are numbers. But comparing int is much faster than string, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think is is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how fast this solution will be but you can try to cnocatenate the two columns and then use isin()

```
X['key'] = X['user_id']+"_"+X['sku_id']
Y['key'] = Y['user_id']+"_"+Y['sku_id']
```

Now just use key to filter X from Y. Please let me know if this improves performance.